# Center an image in a container scale it and crop the remaining

Tags: android

I have this scenario. So the image is larger than the container

[image]

I want it to scale down or scale up depending on the container size but at the same time put it on the center and crop the remaining (horizontally).

So I did something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/header_long"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:dither="true"/>
```

However it looks like this now. The top, bottom, left and right is cropped.

[image]

I want it to be something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like ben75 proposes, you can put your bitmap into am ImageView and use

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

If you want to use your image as a background, consider making it a 9-patch image. They define areas that may be stretched if the image is too small. They also define padding. Note that 9-patch images grow as needed but they never shrink, so make them as small as the smallest size you like them to get.

Comment: I placed the bitmap drawable above into an ImageView and did `centerCrop` but the top and bottom is cropped as if it was not scaled

Comment: did you scale it first before apply `centerCrop`?